# Unity 3D change Object material when player touches it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want my Game Object to change it's material (basically to give the floor another color) when my player touches it.

I came up with this:

```
public Renderer Object;
public Material material;
public Collider collider;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    if (collider.tag == "Player")
    {
        Object.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = material;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

I want to add the script to different Blocks, so not to the player.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `But it doesn't work.` what does that mean exactly? Are these actually triggers? Maybe you rather want [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) instead?

Answer (score 0):

String tags are known to be unreliable. For example:

- "player"!="Player"
- "Player"!="Player "

I recommend using components as tags. To do that:

- create an empty `PlayerTag` component

`PlayerTag.cs`:

```
public class PlayerTag : MonoBehaviour
{

}
```

- add it to your player prefab
- look for that component in your trigger code `other.GetComponentInParent<PlayerTag>();`

`ChangeMaterialOnPlayerTriggerEnter.cs`:

```
public class ChangeMaterialOnPlayerTriggerEnter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] MeshRenderer _meshRenderer;
    [SerializeField] Material _material;
    void OnTriggerEnter ( Collider other )
    {
        var player = other.GetComponentInParent<PlayerTag>();
        if( player!=null ) _meshRenderer.material = _material;
    }
}
```

[image: change material on player TriggerEnter]

[image: player tag component]

[image: trigger]

Comment: Tried in a few ways, doesn't work for me.

Comment: `OnTriggerEnter` is called is specific situation i.e. when a rigidbody overlaps with a `Collider` flagged as trigger.

I added images to visualize that (it's play mode ofc).

Comment: It works but if I use is Trigger my player will just fall through the floor.

Comment: You can create 2 separate colliders on a gameobject: one for collision and one for triggering (often bigger)

Comment: I tried using another box collider and a mesh collider but then it won't change the color.

Comment: Try separating those concerns into two gameobjects: one for collision and rendering and the other one for trigger + `ChangeMaterialOnPlayerTriggerEnter` script